# Coffeescript/Javascript loop not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have a simple coffeescript to process a specific selector (part_ids) ..

```
 alert "Starting  blines  " + $("[id*=part_id]").length
 for bl in $("[id*=part_id]")
   do(bl) ->
     procBl bl

  procBl  = (bl)  ->
     alert "# of children "  + bl.children().length
```

First alert show 2 items are on the page.
For loop runs -- however the procBl doesn't print the alert (it quietly exits)
It appears that bl that's being iterated and passed to the function is not the correct object and I can't figure out what's it and wrong with this code -

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bl` passed into `procBl` function is not a jQuery instance, but plain DOM element. Wrap it with `$()` to use `children` method:

```
  procBl  = (bl)  ->
     alert "# of children "  + $(bl).children().length
```

... or use `$.fn.each` method to iterate over `$("[id*=part_id]")` collection.

Comment: dfsq -- wrapping with $ works in the for loop but doesn't work in the function -- it exits quietly -- could you show me the syntax for using the .each -- on the collection  .. thanks .. the

Comment: `$("[id*=part_id]").each -> alert "# of children " + $(this).children().length;`

Comment: Thanks .. as I said it works in the for loop .. but I still can't call the function with bl or $(bl) :-(